# HVAC blower motor runs for a few minutes then stops

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, fans, central-air, testing

I have a Trane X80 furnace with a Nest gen 3 thermostat. This combo has worked flawlessly for a summer and a winter. I just switched back to "cool" and the fan and compressor come on, but the fan stops after a few minutes (while the compressor continues to run). I contacted Nest and after a lengthy list of diagnostics, they determined that the Nest baseplate was bad and sent me a new one. I replaced it and the problem did not change. I pinged Nest again and they said that it must, then, be an HVAC problem. If I jump the fan wire (G) and power wire (R) wire, the fan runs for a couple minutes then shuts down. I'm guessing I have a fan going bad but just wanted to confirm before I replace it.

I welcome and thank you for your input.

Comment: When you say "*the fan*", are you talking about the blower in the furnace or the fan in the condensing unit?  When you say "*a few seconds*", how long exactly are you talking about?  Does the fan get up to speed, or shut off just as it gets up to speed?

Comment: Sorry, yes...the blower motor in the furnace housing. Yes, the fan gets up to full speed, blows for about two minutes and then shuts off.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are correct that the fan itself is the problem.

Your diagnostic test of supplying power to just the fan, and the fact that the symptoms stayed with the fan, sound like conclusive evidence.